# The limit of $ \lim_{x\to \infty} (\frac{ x-3}{x+2})^x$

Tags: limits

My attempt,

After some algebra we get

$$\left(1-\frac{5}{x+2}\right)^x$$

Now I expanded using binomial series $(x=n)$ and got

$$1-\frac{5x}{x+2} + \frac{(x^2-x) (25)}{2(x+2)^2}............$$

Now, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: DDD4C4U , it is equal to $e^{-5}$ . Use the result, $\lim_{x→∞} (R(x))^x = \lim_{x→∞} e ^{x\ln (R(x))}$ where $R(x)$ is the rational function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x \ln (\frac {x-3} {x+2})=x\ln (1-\frac  5 {x+2}) =x[ -\frac  5 {x+2}+o(\frac  1 {x+2})) \to -5$. Taking exponential we see that the given limit is $e^{-5}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{x-3}{x+2} \right)^x=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\left( 1 + \frac{1}{\frac{x+2}{-5}} \right)^{\frac{x+2}{-5}}\right)^\frac{-5x}{x+2}$$

Comment: I dont think I would have thought of this in a 100 years

Comment: Check other answers then...

Comment: I don't know how you would continue from there, because as far as I know $\lim_{x \to  \infty} f(x) ^ {g(x) }$ is not equal to $\lim_{x \to  \infty} f(x) ^ {\lim_{x \to  \infty} g(x)} $

Comment: @Deepak your method is different because you used only multiplication and that does work : $$\left(1-\frac{5}{x+2}\right)^x=\left(1-\frac{5}{x+2}\right)^{x+2} . \left(1-\frac{5}{x+2}\right)^{-2}$$ you can also divide by $5$ and use the fifth power like this:$$\left(1-\frac{5}{x+2}\right)^x=\left(\left(1-\frac{5}{x+2}\right)^{\frac {x+2}{5}} . \left(1-\frac{5}{x+2}\right)^{\frac {-2}{5}}\right) ^ 5$$

Comment: @Elaqqad: that general formula holds if $f(x)$ has a positive limit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle \frac 5{x+2} = \frac 1y \implies x = 5y-2$.

$\displaystyle (1-\frac{5}{x+2})^x\\ = (1-\frac 1y)^{5y-2} = ((1-\frac 1y)^y)^5\cdot (1- \frac 1y)^{-2}$

Taking the limit, that is $\displaystyle (e^{-1})^5 \cdot 1 = e^{-5}$.

Comment: This is the way. +1

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{gather}
L = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac 5 {x-2}\right)^x \\
\log L = \lim_{x \to \infty} x \log \left(1-\frac{5}{x-2}\right) \\
\end{gather}$$
Use a taylor series expansion for $\log \left(1-\frac{5}{x-2}\right)$:
$$
\log L = \lim_{x \to \infty} x \left( - \frac{5}{x-2} + \frac{5^2}{2(x-2)^2} + ... \right)$$
Now, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-5x}{x-2} = -5$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-5x}{(x-2)^n} = 0 , n>1$. Putting these together, 
$$
\log L = -5 $$
Take an exponent both sides to get 
$$L = e^{-5}$$

Comment: Edited to remove errors and add some verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

Let us rewrite your binomial series as so:

$$\left( 1 - \frac{5}{x+2} \right)^x = \sum_{k=0}^x \binom x k \left( \frac{-5}{x+2} \right)^k$$

Note that, for integers $x$,

$$\binom x k = \frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k+1)}{k!} = \frac{x^k}{k!}+\mathcal O(x^{k-1})$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{k=0}^x \binom x k \left( \frac{-5}{x+2} \right)^k \sim \sum_{k=0}^x \frac{(-5)^k x^{k}}{k!(x+2)^k}$$

Take $x\to\infty$. Then $x^k/(x+2)^k \to 1$ and the sum goes to infinity and thus

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{5}{x+2} \right)^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-5)^k }{k!}$$

The latter sum is the power series for $e^x$, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k/k!$, evaluated at $x=-5$. Thus, the limit is $e^{-5}$.

Comment: wait, that approximation step, Can you elaborate on when you can do that? I considered it but didn't go for it. Like when is it mathematically correct to do that??

Comment: You might want to look into [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for a proper explanation. It is just, essentially, a termwise application of that since the corresponding terms of each sum, when divided by each other, approach the same limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: technically speaking isn't the 'k' also going to infinity, how come that didn't cause problems?

Comment: Because at all points in our process up until $x \to \infty$ was used, the series is finite so that's not an issue. When $x \to \infty$ is used, then $k$, as the index for the series, can also go to infinity, but the power series for $e^x$ converges for all $x$ and likewise has an index that ranges to infinity, so there's no issues there.